# Is $\mathrm{span}\{ S \} = R^n$ the same as saying $S$ spans $R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I searched and googled. Just not sure of the grammar when working with span.

$\mathrm{span}\{S\} = R^n$

is that the same as $S$ spans $R^n$ ?

Or is it $\mathrm{span}\{S\} = R^n$ only if $S$ is linearly independent, but $S$ can span $R^2$ as long as $Ax=b$ is consistent but not necessarily independent?

Thanks.

Comment: What are those brackets in $span\{S\}$?  Is there a singleton set $\{S\}$?  I may write simply $\mathrm{span}\;S$ for the span of a set $S$.

Comment: '$Span (S)=\mathbb R^{n}$' has nothing to do with independence. It simply means every vector is  a linear combination of vectors from $S$.

Comment: But is that the same as say S spans R^n?

Comment: You should check how the notation is defined in your text or other source, but yes, the only reasonable meaning that occurs to me is that the set $S$ of vectors spans $\mathbb R^n$, and this does not require linear independence for $S$.

Comment: Thanks hardmath